# Image in Xamarin forms

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Some images are not displayed on the image object(Xamarin forms), especially those taken with the phone's camera.
Are there any rules for displaying an image? I did not find anything to help me in the Microsoft documentation!

For example, I put four Images to display. The first image is displayed but the next 3 images are not displayed!

I would be grateful if those who worked in this field would provide guidance

[ِDisplayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1mnO.jpg)

[Not Displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm2bN.jpg)

[Not Displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tpo5z.jpg)

[Not Displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgLUo.jpg)

```
 <Image
 Source="Moto.jpg"
 VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
 HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: You will need to provide us with a lot more information I am afraid, are you just using the Image control, or are you trying to do a carousel? That kind of thing and providing us with samples of your code will allow us to help you much faster.

Comment: <Image   Source="BBB.jpg"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               />

Comment: You are using a relative image path. You camera pics are stored in some other folder, like /DCIM/Camera/... in Android. And to access that path, you will need permission.

Comment: *"I put four Images to display. The first image is displayed but the next 3 images are not displayed!"*  To understand exactly what you did: 1) Make the XAML page as simple as you can, yet still has the bug. 2) Add to question the **entire** .xaml and .xaml.cs source for that (simple) page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

image properties -> Build Action -> "Android Resource"

Answer (score 0):

I place the four images in project (iOS/Android) , it shows as expected .

[image] [image]

---

Here are some suggestions for you

1. Place the images file in correct folder .

   **iOS** : `Resources` folder or `Asset Catalogs`.

   [image]

   **Android** : `Resources/drawable` folder .

   [image]

   Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images.
2. Check the  `image name` in xaml , it should correspond to the name in folder(it is case-sensitive).
3. Avoid the image control overlapping each other .

```
//this is my test code 
 <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Source="a.jpg" />
        <Image Source="b.jpg" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Image Source="c.jpg" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Image Source="d.jpg" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
```